# Terraform directory ".terraform/modules" naming convention

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

## Background

When we import a module in terraform and run `terraform init`, this module will be downloaded and stored under the path `.terraform/modules/*`. This directory contains folders with an hexadecimal name and a file `modules.json` which, among other things, maps the name of the module with its physical location.

## Question

Is there a schema which defines how the hexadecimal name of the folder is created?

Thanks

Comment: Can you share some code snippets here?